# How to perform Full Text Search in Couchbase using Spring Data Repository

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have created a full-text search index for my bucket and I am able to use it in web UI and get some search results. Still, I can't find an appropriate example of how to create a repository or method in the existing repository using Spring Data Couchbase for performing a full-text search.

Here is my index definition:

```
{
  "type": "fulltext-index",
  "name": "FTI_Users",
  "uuid": "48316628ed720269",
  "sourceType": "gocbcore",
  "sourceName": "Users",
  "sourceUUID": "d8a535cb7b46f6b4f85b24bc0887e740",
  "planParams": {
    "maxPartitionsPerPIndex": 1024,
    "indexPartitions": 1
  },
  "params": {
    "doc_config": {
      "docid_prefix_delim": "",
      "docid_regexp": "",
      "mode": "type_field",
      "type_field": "type"
    },
    "mapping": {
      "analysis": {},
      "default_analyzer": "standard",
      "default_datetime_parser": "dateTimeOptional",
      "default_field": "_all",
      "default_mapping": {
        "dynamic": true,
        "enabled": true
      },
      "default_type": "_default",
      "docvalues_dynamic": false,
      "index_dynamic": true,
      "store_dynamic": true,
      "type_field": "_type"
    },
    "store": {
      "indexType": "scorch",
      "segmentVersion": 15
    }
  },
  "sourceParams": {}
}
```

All I found is this short Spring documentation [https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#:~:text=for%20more%20information.-,Full%20Text%20Search,-(FTS)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/current/reference/html/#:%7E:text=for%20more%20information.-,Full%20Text%20Search,-(FTS)) where they suggest using `Cluster` class.

First of all, I would like to use the Spring repository instead of this class if it's possible. If not, how do I convert `SearchResult` that returns from

```
cluster.searchQuery("FTI_Users", SearchQuery.queryString(query))
```

into a list of my entity objects?

Answer (score 0):

There is no integration for FTS in spring data couchbase repositories.

Use 8.3 Object Conversion for object mapping. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/4.4.5/reference/html/#couchbase.transactions